# How many partial order relations are there over N, the set of positive integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have been trying to calculate it in several ways but I get stuck when it comes to many combinatorial issues... Like taking the number of possible relations and subtract the number different kinds of relations that do not meet the criteria. I could use some help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** How many permutations does $\Bbb N$ has? This alone gives you a lower bound, with a set of distinct linear orders, all isomorphic to the usual ordering of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: How does it help me to know how many permutations are there? 
It confuses me a little...

Comment: Show that from each permutation you can define a different linear order. Isomorphic, but nonetheless different.

Comment: טוב זה מסבך אותי ככה, איך היית מנסח את זה בעברית, זה היה מקל עליי חחח

Comment: תודה על המענה, קודם כל.

Comment: הכוונה בחסם מלרע הוא חסם מלרע של העוצמה של קבוצת היחסים, או חסם מלרע שהוא איבר כלשהו ב-N ?

Comment: מתוך כל תמורה אפשר להגדיר סדר חלקי (אפילו קווי) חדש על הטבעיים, שפשוט איזומורפי לסדר הרגיל שלהם. זה נותן לנו, באופן מיידי קבוצה די גדולה של סדר חלקיים. זה אומר שקבוצת הסדרים החלקיים היא לפחות בעוצמה שתתקבל. משם זה כבר די מיידי.

Comment: If you apply this on a finite set, like A={1,2,3}, so let a={(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)} be a permutation. If it is to generate an order relation, you get, by transitivity {(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1)} which is a contradiction. My question is, how can I be sure it is not going to happen with A=N?

Comment: Given a bijection $F\colon\Bbb N\to A$ we can define $\leq_F$ on $A$ by: $a\leq_F b\iff F^{-1}(a)\leq F^{-1}(b)$. Sit and verify that this is indeed a linear ordering on $A$. Now pick $A=\Bbb N$ and show that given two different permutations on $\Bbb N$, they induce two different linear orders.

Comment: Oh! I get it...Thanks again. :)

Comment: I can't seem to show why every permutation induce a unique relation... I know it is true. I tried to prove by induction but it is mindblowing :(

Comment: And would it matter if I used F instead of F inverse?

Comment: What if F(k)=G(k)=0?

Comment: D'oh, yeah, the hint there is wrong. I'll delete and give you a better hint. :-)

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time, and sorry for bothering :)

Comment: You don't need induction. If $G(n)\neq F(n)$ and without loss of generality $G(n)<F(n)$, then $\{(k,n)\mid k<_G n\}$ is strictly smaller than $\{(k,n)\mid k<_F n\}$, so the orders $<_G$ and $<_F$ must be distinct.

Comment: Great! Thanks :)

Comment: Can I say there are א0! permutations? 
In another question I was stuck with is and it legitimacy...

Comment: Yes, I remember that. You can, that's the definition of $\aleph_0!$.